# Erro ao consumir webservice wsdl com PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Estou a dias com este problema, preciso consumir um webservice wsdl com php.

Segue meu código

```
$cliente = new SoapClient('http://ws.tntbrasil.com.br:81/tntws/CalculoFrete?wsdl');

$funcao = 'calculaFrete';
$parametros = array(
  'calculaFrete' =>
      array(
        'cepDestino'                        => '95045080',
        'vlMercadoria'                      => '300.85',
        'psReal'                            => '30.000',
        'cdDivisaoCliente'                  => '1',
        'cepOrigem'                         => '95032620',
        'login'                             => 'marketing@ludocar.com.br',
        'nrIdentifClienteDest'              => '00010010099',
        'nrIdentifClienteRem'               => '10668759000109',
        'nrInscricaoEstadualDestinatario'   => '',
        'nrInscricaoEstadualRemetente'      => '0290501580',
        'senha'                             => '',
        'tpFrete'                           => 'C',
        'tpPessoaDestinatario'              => 'F',
        'tpPessoaRemetente'                 => 'J',
        'tpServico'                         => 'RNC',
        'tpSituacaoTributariaDestinatario'  => 'CO',
        'tpSituacaoTributariaRemetente'     => 'ME'
    )
);
$resultado = $cliente->__soapCall($funcao, $parametros);
```

Esta me retornando o erro

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://ws.tntbrasil.com.br:81/tntws/CalculoFrete?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://ws.tntbrasil.com.br:81/tntws/CalculoFrete?wsdl" in /home/eggecom/public_html/tnt/calculaFrete.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /home/eggecom/public_html/tnt/calculaFrete.php(19): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://ws.tntbr...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/eggecom/public_html/tnt/calculaFrete.php on line 19
```

Já tentei de inúmeras formas e entrei em contato com o fornecedor do webservice onde não me deu o suporte desejado porém me garantiu sobre as variáveis estarem certas.

PHP Version 5.6
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: de seu servidor PHP, você consegue acessar essa URL http://ws.tntbrasil.com.br:81/tntws/CalculoFrete?wsdl ?

Comment: Sim, sem problema algum.

Comment: Se vc rodar esse código --> `echo ("<pre>" . htmlentities(file_get_contents('http://ws.tntbrasil.com.br:81/tntws/CalculoFrete?wsdl')) . "</pre>");` o conteúdo do WSDL aparece?

Comment: Sim, testei agora e retornou:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<definitions  xmlns:tns="http://service.calculoFrete.mercurio.com" targetNamespace="http://service.calculoFrete.mercurio.com" name="CalculoFrete">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://service.calculoFrete.mercurio.com" schemaLocation="http://ws.tntbrasil.com.br:81/tntws/CalculoFrete?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema> [...]

Comment: Só por via das dúvidas, tente adicionar a seguinte linha antes de $cliente = new Soap....   `libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);`. O que acontece agora?

Comment: Nada, mesmo erro :/

Comment: Uma última sugestão: remova o libxml_dis... que falei antes e deixe o $cliente assim: `$cliente = new SoapClient('http://ws.tntbrasil.com.br:81/tntws/CalculoFrete?wsdl', array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));`. De qualquer forma, está aparentando algo com o seu server mesmo. Se não der certo a sugestão, comece a olhar seu firewall se está permitindo tráfego na porta 81, ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Continua:
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [ns0:Server] java.lang.NullPointerException
Muito obrigado até agora!

Comment: Resolvi a questão: Dentro do $parametros o array deve se chamar in0 e não calculaFrete.

Answer (score -1):

Se ajudar...consegui consumir implementando o seguinte código:

```
$xmlr = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.calculoFrete.mercurio.com" xmlns:mod="http://model.vendas.lms.mercurio.com">
               <soapenv:Header/>
               <soapenv:Body>
                  <ser:calculaFrete>
                     <ser:in0>
                        <mod:login>' . $user_login . '</mod:login>
                        <mod:senha></mod:senha>
                        <mod:nrIdentifClienteRem>' . $cnpj . '</mod:nrIdentifClienteRem>
                        <mod:nrIdentifClienteDest>' . $idclientedest . '</mod:nrIdentifClienteDest>
                        <mod:tpFrete>' . $tipo_frete . '</mod:tpFrete>
                        <mod:tpServico>' . $tipo_servico . '</mod:tpServico>
                        <mod:cepOrigem>' . $cep_origem . '</mod:cepOrigem>
                        <mod:cepDestino>' . $cep_dst . '</mod:cepDestino>
                        <mod:vlMercadoria>' . number_format($valor_nf, 2, '.', '') . '</mod:vlMercadoria>
                        <mod:psReal>' . number_format($peso_total, 3, '.', '') . '</mod:psReal>
                        <mod:nrInscricaoEstadualRemetente>' . $ie . '</mod:nrInscricaoEstadualRemetente>
                        <mod:nrInscricaoEstadualDestinatario></mod:nrInscricaoEstadualDestinatario>
                        <mod:tpSituacaoTributariaRemetente>' . $situacao_trib . '</mod:tpSituacaoTributariaRemetente>
                        <mod:tpSituacaoTributariaDestinatario>CO</mod:tpSituacaoTributariaDestinatario>
                        <mod:cdDivisaoCliente>' . $divisao_cliente . '</mod:cdDivisaoCliente>
                        <mod:tpPessoaRemetente>' . $tipo_pessoa . '</mod:tpPessoaRemetente>
                        <mod:tpPessoaDestinatario>F</mod:tpPessoaDestinatario>
                     </ser:in0>
                  </ser:calculaFrete>
               </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>';

// Chama o webservice                               
$location_URL = 'http://ws.tntbrasil.com.br/tntws/CalculoFrete?wsdl';
$uri = 'http://service.calculoFrete.mercurio.com';
$action_URL = 'http://ws.tntbrasil.com.br/tntws/CalculoFrete';

$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
        'location' => $location_URL,
        'uri'      => $uri,
        'trace'    => 1,
        ));

$xml = $client->__doRequest($xmlr, $location_URL, $action_URL, 1);

// Le o XML
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1');
$dom->loadXml($xml);

// Obtem os dados
$municipio = $dom->getElementsByTagName('nmMunicipioDestino')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$vltotal = $dom->getElementsByTagName('vlTotalFrete')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$prazo = $dom->getElementsByTagName('prazoEntrega')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```